# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput' while performing Random Forest Classification

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am performing random forest classification on [movie_metadata](https://www.kaggle.com/code/harshadeepvattikunta/predicting-movie-success/input) from Kaggle. I want to classify them as flop, average and hit. I am new to machine learning and any help and positive criticism would be highly appreciated.
PS: I have been through similar questions and tried everything. Also, I am learning random forest so please do not suggest changing it.

[This is what the data looks like after encoding and scaling:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXpbw.png)

Here is what I have done:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y_train.shape # (3004, 12)
x_train.shape # (3004, 12)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
```

Here is where the error is showing:

```
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-244-fdf0fc8db087> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    216         "multilabel-sequences",
    217     ]:
--> 218         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    219 
    220 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'
```

Comment: Why does `y_train` have 12 columns?

Comment: @BenReiniger I used 'train_test_split' to train the data and then scaled the data using StandardScaler which gave this output. I checked, and my 'y' is 1d.

Comment: Did you maybe have the wrong order of variable assignment out of the split (switching `X_test` and `y_train`)?